# Number formatting not working in Mulesoft dataview

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am trying to format number in below json string in Mulesoft.

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Date": "10/12/2012",
      "AccountNumber": 123456,
      "Amount": 1424511.76
    },
    {
      "Date": "10/12/2012",
      "AccountNumber": 123456,
      "Amount": 80123.86
    }
  ]
}
```

My data view:

```
 %dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=false

(payload.Data map ((payload01 , indexOfpayload01) -> {
"Trade Date" : payload01.Date, 
"Account": payload01.AccountNumber,
"Amount": payload01.Amount as :string { format: "#,###.00##"} 

}))
```

I want to create CSV file with this code. But it is adding "\" with commas after formatting numbers. For first Amount I am getting

```
"1\,424\,511.76"
```

I am expecting formatted number as

```
1,424,511.76
```

I am not able to understand why it is adding "\" character with comma.
Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is escaping the commas because you are using a CSV(Comma Separated Value) so it will break downstream probably otherwise.

Depending on who needs to read this CSV file, you could possibly quote the values instead:

```
 %output application/csv quoteValues=true
```

Or:

```
%output application/csv quoteValues=true ,escape =" "
```

or maybe change the CSV to pipe delimited or some other separator:

```
%output application/csv separator="|"
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. It is working as expected. Thank you very much. Keep up the good work!